# Adding template directory in django

Tags: python, django

I just wanted to understand something about adding a templates folder in django. This is the code for including my templates folder, that django conveniently made for me:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # This includes the templates folder
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
)
```

What I do not understand is the part with `'templates'`, why is it not `'/templates'`, or even `\\templates` in the case of something Unix based? I come here after reading this [article](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html), in particular the part about *Template Loading*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path.join` is building the absolute path based on the operating system being used.

Here, Django is computing the templates directory by getting the path. Here, windows would have included a `\\`, hence the `.replace`

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Comment: So, its pretty much the same path that I would just type into cmd?

Comment: Pretty much - yes. Just that an inbuilt python library is being used for the join